# local list in functions python

Tags: python, recursion, local

I want to make a list local inside a recursive function.

`def rec(chk,i):`
here chk is list and i is an integer
i repeat the recursion for 4  times and expect the out to be

> {'chk': [], 'i': 0}
>   {'chk': [1], 'i': 1}
>   {'chk': [1, 2], 'i': 2}
>   {'chk': [1, 2, 3], 'i': 3}
>   {'chk': [1, 2, 3], 'i': 3}
>   {'chk': [1, 2], 'i': 2}
>   {'chk': [1], 'i': 1}

But instead it gives me:

> {'chk': [], 'i': 0}
>   {'chk': [1], 'i': 1}
>   {'chk': [1, 2], 'i': 2}
>   {'chk': [1, 2, 3], 'i': 3}
>   {'chk': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'i': 3}
>   {'chk': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'i': 2}
>   {'chk': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'i': 1}

what should i do to get it in the right way.
Thanks in advance.
for reference here is my code:

```
flag=0
def rec(chk,i):
    global flag
    print(locals())
    i+=1
    chk.append(i)
    if(i==4):
        flag=1
    if(flag==1):
        return
    else:
        rec(chk,i)
    print(locals())
rec([],0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is happening because you are altering that list without copying it. So the list you altered in each recursion is always the same one(Points to the same memory value).

Try it like this;

```
flag=0
def rec(chk,i):
    global flag
    print(locals())
    i+=1
    chk.append(i)
    if(i==4):
        flag=1
    if(flag==1):
        return
    else:
        rec(chk[:],i)
    print(locals())
rec([],0)
```

`chk[:]` is equivelant to `list(chk)`. As Till suggested. If you are dealing with **lists under a list**. You'll need [Deep copy](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/deepCopying.htm).

Answer (score 1):

- Get rid of the global `flag`, that complicates the recursion unnecessarily
- Do not modify the original list but create a copy (`chk + [i]` will create a new concatenated list, while `chk.append` modifies the original one)

So:

```
def rec(chk,i):
  print(locals())
  i += 1
  chk = chk + [i]
  if i != 4:
    rec(chk, i)
    print(locals())

rec([],0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your implementation is that the recursive calls do not receive a copy of the list but simply a reference to the same list. Changing the recursive call to

```
rec(list(chk), i)
```

gives the desired output. The call to `list` creates a copy of the list. You can find a more detailed overview of how python handles arguments [here](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/).

Answer (score 0):

You should alway remember, that parameters in python are "by reference" and not by value. So you do not handle a different list in each recursion, you work with one and the same every time. To get what you want, you should always make a copy of the list.

```
flag=0
def rec(chk,i):
    lst=list(chk)
    global flag
    print(locals())
    i+=1
    lst.append(i)
    if(i==4):
        flag=1
    if(flag==1):
        return
    else:
        rec(lst,i)
    print(locals())
rec([],0)
```